# Word meaning "clear" or "remove" and starting with an O?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, synonyms

Is there a word with a meaning similar to "clear," "clear out," or "remove," or perhaps "fight," but starting with the letter O?

I want to start an initiative at work to gradually clear out warnings from our source code base. I really like acronyms, so I'd like to name it with one. I was thinking of a "grass roots" initiative about "warnings" and came up with "GROW" for the acronym (which is also nice as it will improve the software), but I'm having trouble finding a suitable word for the O. (The whole phrase would then be "Grass Roots *O-doing something with* Warnings.")

I've thought of "ousting," but it doesn't really fit. "Obliterating" feels a bit too strong (especially as the process will be gradual). Is there a better word?

Comment: [omit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/omit)

Comment: Nothing much comes to mind... "overturn" doesn't really fit here either. Maybe you need to come up with some acronym other than "grow" :)

Comment: How about "Good Riddance, O Warnings!" or "Good Riddance, Obnoxious Warnings!" ? Or the plain "Getting Rid Of Warnings".

Comment: You do obliterate each individual warning, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try GREW instead and maybe use words like Erase, Eliminate, or Expel?

Comment: Nice idea, +1. The tagline could then be "I wish our software GREW."

Comment: "I wish our software GREW." It sounds as if It hasn't grown and now you are sad about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll chime in:   DAWN,  for Destroy All Warnings Now.    Nice contrast between the restful but optimistic feelings implied by the word "dawn" and the aggressive stance of the actual meaning.